# Command to copy code from one file to another

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

I would like to know whether there is any command to copy PHP code from file A to file B. I am not using GIT or SVN for my project, so would like to know whether it is possible to keep these 2 files synchronized.

Would be great to know about a command that just pasts the lines from file A that are not present in File b.

Note : My client's developer will code directly in live site, where else I will copy the code from my local to his site. So I cannot use scp or mv command to replicate my local copy in live site.

Comment: Wont rsync command do this? Edit* : yes this cant do code level synchronization, only file level can be done. Just now read about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think below should work

`fgrep -vxf file2 file1 >>file2`

or you can use

Let's say we have a file. Call it "version 1". Then you copy it to another place, and make some edits. Call this "version 2a". Then copy it to yet another place, and make some different edits. Call this "version 2b".

Now, the simple way to merge changes from 2a to 2b is to find the difference between 1 and 2a, and apply that to 2b.

```
diff -u version1 version2a >diff2a
cd ../path/to/2b
patch -p0 <../back/to/diff2a
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks will try this out now. really looks interesting.